# How to hide and show multi registration

Tags: php, jquery

I try to make a multi registration form in 2 steps.

And let work the buttons.

How do I hide step two until proceed step 1, than hide step 1.

```
<div class="user-register-field-1">

    <form name="register" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post">

        <fieldset>

            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_post" />

            <button type="submit" class="small radius">
                <?php _e("Continue Step 2", 'ctg_housing');?>
            </button>


        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="user-register-field-2">

    <form name="user-register-2" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post">

        <fieldset>

            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_post" />

            <button type="submit" class="small radius">
                <?php _e("Create Account", 'ctg_housing');?>
            </button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This reads more like a job specification than a question.

Comment: Both fields still appears on the same page!

Comment: Try tabs and it will be like steps.

Comment: this isn't a free coding service. You are expected to at least make an attempt to solve it yourself. There are plenty of tutorials and even plugins for doing this already existing which you could find and try with a small amount of searching online.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="user-register-field-1">

    <form name="register" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post">

        <fieldset>

            <input type="text" name="page" >
            <input type="text" name="action" >

            <button type="submit" class="small radius">
                <?php _e("Continue Step 2", 'ctg_housing');?>
            </button>


        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="user-register-field-2">

    <form name="user-register-2" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post">

        <fieldset>

            <input type="text" name="page">
            <input type="text" name="action">

            <button type="submit" class="small radius">
                <?php _e("Create Account", 'ctg_housing');?>
            </button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.user-register-field-2{
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.user-register-field-1 form").on("submit", function(){
    $("div.user-register-field-1").hide();
    $("div.user-register-field-2").show();
  });
});
```

Check also my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cz5kyaqL/ 
I hope I understood you right and could help